# Retrieve corner coordinates of image given resolution and center point

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm going through an image dataset which has image pixel coordinate and the resolution of the image. Is there any way to map that information to corner coordinates of the image.

For instance if the image pixel coordinates are -403059.626, -12869811.372 and image is 4168 x 3632 pixels, Is it possible to extract the real world coordinates of the four corners of each image in the rectangle? We can assume the size of the pixel as 1 unit

Comment: Does `x=-403059.626, y=-12869811.372` represent one pixel coordinate? How was this pixel coordinate mapped?

Comment: @zindarod That is the centroid pixel of the image

Comment: Ah, ok. Do you know how this point was computed? In OpenCV negative coordinates mean that the point exists outside image boundary and these coordinates are also greater than the image dimensions.

Comment: The point is the stage point from which the image is captured.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I guess we can assume the images have pixel spacing

Comment: @CrisLuengo Sorry I might have misunderstood, I'm looking for real world coordinates assuming no rotations is taken for account

Comment: @CrisLuengo Sorry for delay in response, Regarding the size of pixel, we can consider as 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `p = (-403059.626, -12869811.372)` is the pixel in the middle of the image, and an image of size `s = (4168, 3632)` pixels, and a pixel size of 1 (meaning pixels are in the same units as the location given by `p`), then the coordinates of the top-left corner can be computed as follows:

```
q = p - s/2 = ( -403059.626 - 4168/2 , -12869811.372 - 3632/2 )
```

The `s/2` value above can be computed differently depending on what you consider the pixel in the middle of the image. Here I assume the top-left pixel has index (0,0), and the pixel in the middle has index (4168/2,3632/2).

The above assumes no rotation (i.e. the image axes are aligned with the coordinate system), and no distortion (it is possible that the camera adds distortion to the image, causing the pixel pitch to change in different parts of the image).

The bottom-right corner then has coordinates:

```
r = q + s-1 = p + s/2 - 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, How can I calculate the bottom left and top right corner coordinates?

Comment: @naveenmarri: I thought that that was obvious... The first element of `q` is the left edge, the first element of `r` is the right edge. The second element of these two are the top and bottom edges. Combine these 4 values to get each corner: `bottom-left = (q(1),r(2))`, `top-right = (q(2),r(1))`.